# High memory consumption with smart pointers c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, memory-consumption

I am confused about using pointers/smartpointer in c++.
We want to capture Packets from an NIC.  We use [PF_RING ZC](http://www.ntop.org/) for capturing packets as follow:

```
typedef folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string> ZCTask;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ZCTask> ZCTask_ptr;

void runZCConnection() {
        ZCTask_ptr activeBufferConnection(new folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string>(200000));
        LOG_INFO("capture_loop for connections: Entering >> SHARE POINTER .");
            int h = 0;
        for (;;) {
            if (likely(pfring_zc_recv_pkt(zqc, &buffer_connection, _wait_for_packet) >= 0)) {
                u_char *pkt_data = pfring_zc_pkt_buff_data(buffer_connection, zqc);
                std::string payload(pkt_data + _ConnectionHeaderSize, pkt_data + _snapLengthConnection); 

                if (activeBufferConnection->isFull()) {
                    LOG_INFO("ZC Active buffer Connction is full");
                    _buffersConnection.add(activeBufferConnection);
                    LOG_INFO(">> after add. USAGEG   %ld", activeBufferConnection.use_count());
                    activeBufferConnection.reset(new folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string>(200000));
                    LOG_INFO(">> after reset. USAGEG   %ld", activeBufferConnection.use_count());
folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string>(_bufferSizeConnection + 1);
                    if (h++ > 25) {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                activeBufferConnection->write(payload);
                continue;
            }
        }
        
for (int a = 0; a < 25; a++) {
            //get new task                                   
            Node* node = _buffersConnection.get2();
            {
                ZCTask_ptr zcTaskConnection = node->Data;
                delete node;
                node = NULL;
                LOG_INFO(">> After node delete. USAGEG   %ld", 
                LOG_INFO("connection buffer : %d", a);

            }
        }
        LOG_INFO("delete");
    } //packet consumer
```

As it can be seen, first of all we store the packets on a [folly SPMC](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ProducerConsumerQueue.h) queue in runZCWrapper. When the queue is full, is written into a linked list named _ buffersConnection.

Capturing works fine and we save all packets. Our problem with this peace of code is its high memory consumption. When a packed arrives, the activeBufferConnection stores it. When number of packets raises up to 1000000, new activeBufferConnection created and last one stored in a linked list named buffersconnections. We set the number of buffersconnections to 25.

As it can be seen in above piece of code, we are using smart pointers for
Pointing to activeBufferConnection . when a activeBufferConnection is full, its pointer passed to “add” method of buffersconnections.

Here is some codes of our ArchiveList Class which is used in runZCConnection;

```
class ArchiveList {
    typedef folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string> ZCTask;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ZCTask> ZCTask_ptr;
private:
    Node* root;Node* last;    
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;
public:

    ArchiveList() {
        root = new Node();
        last = root;
    }

    Node*
    get2() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        while (root->Next == NULL) {
            LOG_INFO("get null");
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }
        LOG_INFO("1");
        Node* toDelete = root->Next;
        LOG_INFO("1");
        root->Next = toDelete->Next;
        LOG_INFO("1");
        return toDelete;
    }

    void
    add(ZCTask_ptr item) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        Node* newItem = new Node();
        newItem->Data = item;
        newItem->Prev = last;
        last->Next = newItem;
        last = newItem;

        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
        LOG_INFO("+");
    }

};
```

When the number of activeBufferConnection increased to 25, the first loop finished and the second loop starts to work. The second loop deletes all 25 elements of Linked List.
Here is some codes of our Node Class which is used in runZCConnection;

```
class Node {
public:
    typedef folly::ProducerConsumerQueue<std::string> ZCTask;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<ZCTask> ZCTask_ptr;

    Node() {
        Next = NULL;Prev = NULL;Data = NULL;
    }

    ~Node() {
        Next = NULL;Prev = NULL;
        LOG_INFO(" >> NODE DCTOR. USAGEG   %ld", Data.use_count());
        Data.reset();
        LOG_INFO("NODE DCTOR");
    }

    ZCTask_ptr Data;
    Node* Next;
    Node* Prev;
private:    
};
```

The output of [top](http://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/) command is the problem. the first loop of runZCConnection stores packets on some buffers. After deleting the buffers on its secound loop, the memory used by them is not freed and we don’t know why this is happened.

```
                    CPU     MEM
 83698 root         49.3    0.3      0:01.49 ng4-m2
 83698 root         39.1    0.6     0:02.67 ng4-m2
 83698 root         41.5    0.8     0:03.92 ng4-m2
 83698 root         1.3     1.0     0:05.49 ng4-m2
 83698 root         1.0     1.0      0:05.52 ng4-m2
 83698 root         1.7     0.9     0:05.57 ng4-m2
```

As top command shows, the memory is not freed after the program deletes all its buffers. The problem may be related to wrong delete of buffers or maybe related to wrong usage of pointers. We set some logs on some places of the code that returns some informations about of program and its pointer status  .
Here are some lines of output:

```
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:260 : ZC Active buffer Connction is full
INFO    | ArchiveList.h   | add:80 : +
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:262 : >> after add. USAGEG   2
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:264 : >> after reset. USAGEG   1
.
.
.
INFO    | ArchiveList.h   | get2:56 : 1
INFO    | Node.hpp        | ~Node:27 :  >> NODE DCTOR. USAGEG   2
INFO    | Node.hpp        | ~Node:29 : NODE DCTOR
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:286 : >> After node delete. USAGEG   1
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:308 : >> END OF ONE TASK. USAGEG   0
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:310 : connection buffer : 1
.
.
.
INFO    | ZCWrapper.hpp   | runZCConnection:315 : delete
```

How can we resolve the problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Node* newItem = new Node(); - I do not see a delete for this and why is there a mix of smart pointers and raw pointers, maybe keeps thing consistent?

Comment: The C++ memory manager doesn't necessarily release memory back to the OS when you free it, as there's a fair chance that you're going to need it again and getting memory from the OS is costly.

Comment: @SamerTufail  it does not consume a lot of memory. just 20 of them created in this sample. Most of memory allocated for activeBufferConnection. after deleting them, it seems only memory of last item is freed.

Comment: @molbdnilo it does not use freed memory and get more memory until memory usage get high and killed. Is it possible we have memory fragmentation?

Comment: @molbdnilo , malloc_trim is what i should use in my application. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html